# How to write batch (*.bat) script to execute Teradata query using BTEQ?

Tags: sql, batch-file, teradata

Below is the content of my script.bat :

```
@echo off

cd C:\Program Files\Teradata\Client\13.0\bin

bteq .LOGON server/username,password;

select date;

.LOGOFF

@echo off goto end

:end @echo exit
```

I have no problem with the logon, but it seems that bteq can't read my query statement:

> select date;

It keeps prompting for input. Can anyone help me to get bteq to read and execute the query statement?

I've tried the solutions online about input and output file:

```
bteq <myscript.txt> mylog.log
```

but it didn't work either.

Comment: Your batch script isn't a set of commands that work exactly as if they were typed in, they're a set of commands to be executed directly by `cmd.exe`.  Those won't be passed to sub-programs unless you directly pass them in (same line), or write them to files and make the sub-programs read them.  Try this: Launch start -> run -> cmd.exe, and type `select date;`.  It won't understand what you're talking about.  Your cmd.exe pauses executing your batch script while the sub-program runs, then executes the next line (the query) when the sub-program is finished.

Comment: @Merilyn so i can't do it this way? can you help me with other ways?

Answer (score 3):

You are going to need two files, one is a batch and the other one are the commands.

Batch file:

```
echo off
cd C:\bteq_directory\
bteq < c:\commands.txt > c:\output.txt 2>&1
@echo off goto end
:end @echo exit
```

Commands:

```
.LOGON server/username,password
select date;
.LOGOFF
```

**EDIT:**

Removed semicolon after `.LOGON...`

Comment: Hi Michal, thank you for answering, but it still can't work. I get this warning `*** Warning: You must log on before sending DBC/SQL requests.`

Comment: And the same `.LOGON` command with given the same credentials in the interactive mode works fine (and query as well)?

Comment: So if the `logon` works fine, paths and `select` statement are correct I have no idea what else could be wrong. Sorry :-/.

Comment: appreciate your willingness to help, Michal

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but here is what I've found:

I save my BTEQ script in a file called BTScript.txt:

```
.LOGON <servername>/<username>,<password>;
.SET WIDTH 20000;
.SET separator '|';
.EXPORT FILE = C:\TEMP\testBTEQ.txt;
SELECT top 10 * ATABLENAME;
.LOGOFF
.EXIT
```

The setting of width is needed to prevent the data being truncated, it will not go to 20000 chars if the record isnt that long.

To run this I execute (my pc is set up to allow me to double click on the file in windows explorer to do this) on a .bat file the content of which are:

```
echo off
bteq < C:\temp\BTScript.txt > c:\temp\bteqscriptout.txt 2>&1
@echo off goto end
:end @echo exit
```

The second file referred to here will contain the output from BTEQ.